# How to check parameter(in route) before go to controller class in laravel8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have Following Routes

1. /product/category?item=1
2. /product/category?item=2

So,I want to check `item` parameter and go to specific Controller Class like this.

```
Route::get('/product/category', function (Request $request) {
  if($request->input('item') == 1)
      return HomeController's item1 (Function)
  else
      return HomeController's item2 (Function)
});
```

It is possible in Laravel8?
All of the laravel document wrote directly go to controller like this.But,I want to check parameter before going to controller.

```
Route::get('__url', [__Controller::class, '__function']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get items as slug and call controller's method like below in laravel-8

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/product/category/{item}', function($slug, HomeController $controller){
    if($slug == 1):
        return $controller->item1();
    else:
        return $controller->item2();        
    endif;    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I know the way to get 'item' parameter in route but i didn't  understant how to return Controller class after check parameter item.  This point  if($request->input('item') == 1)
     =====> return HomeController's item1 (Function)
  else
     =====> return HomeController's item2 (Function)

Comment: @Deathnote Please check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel container:

```php
Route::get('/product/category', function (Request $request, HomeController $controller) {
  if($request->input('item') == 1)
      return $controller->item1();
  else
      return $controller->item2();
});
```